# Is it possible to implement dropzone to upload images to wordpress media library?

Tags: wordpress, dropzone.js

Can dropzone be setup to handle files and insert them into the wordpress media libary? I have seen some ways to upload files to the server, but I don't know how to include them into the wp library.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked before - and yes it's possible but I wouldn't call it an easy task because you have to add the wordpress code as well into it. 
[See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411257/how-to-integrate-dropzonejs-with-wordpress-media-handler-in-frontend)