# Dropzone.js + <input type="file"> don't work on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dropzone.js

On my WP site I have front-end posting form with:
1) ordinary fields (they're used to show the title, description etc. of the post)
2) dropzone.js field for multiple image uploading (it's used to show gallery of the images)

It perfectly works until I add ordinary `<input type="file">` field to add the featured image of the post. In this case I can catch the images dropped to dropzone field but I cannot get the image from `<input type="file">` field on the server side. What is wrong? Are there any alternative solutions in my case?

My form:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://eventboss.org/wp-content/themes/Travelo/css/dropzone.css">
<form id="createProject" name="new_post" method="post" action="http://eventboss.org/add-property-query/" class="wpcf7-form dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <!-- post name -->
 <fieldset name="name">
  <label for="title">Wine Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="title" value="TestName" tabindex="5" name="title" />
 </fieldset>
                
 <!-- post brief -->
 <fieldset class="trav_tour_brief">
  <label for="trav_tour_brief">Travel Brief</label>
  <input value="TestBrief" type="text" value="" id="trav_tour_brief" tabindex="20" name="trav_tour_brief" />
 </fieldset>
 
 <!-- Gallery -->
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 picture dropzone-previews">
  <div class="egal-center">
   <h5>
    Add Picture
   </h5>
   <div class="upload-box btn">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Featured image -->
 <div class="images">
  -<label for="boss_thumbnail">Front of the Bottle</label>
   <input type="file" name="boss_thumbnail" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />
 </div>

 <fieldset class="submit">
  <button type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div> 
<script src="http://eventboss.org/wp-content/themes/Travelo/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<script>
Dropzone.options.createProject = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100, //1
    maxFiles: 100, //1
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    dictDefaultMessage: '',
    clickable: '.upload-box',
    paramName:"picture",
    init: function() {
        var myDropzone=this;
        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();

        });
        this.on('addedfile', function(file){
            //$('.upload-box').hide();
        });
        this.on('success', function(file){
            //alert(file.xhr.response);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

The part of my server-side code:

```html
media_handle_upload('picture', $pid); // get gallery images from the dropzone.js
media_handle_upload('boss_thumbnail', $pid); // get image from <input type="file"> field
```

Comment: You are going to need a bit more code than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate Dropzonejs with wordpress media handler in frontend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411257/how-to-integrate-dropzonejs-with-wordpress-media-handler-in-frontend)