# Correct way to use wp_enqueue_script() inside the functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using wp_enqueue_script() in my functions.php file to give users on the front end the ability to upload images with dropzone.js. It's making my side extremely slow and I get this error:

```
wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks.
```

Here's the problematic code it works great and does exactly what I want but slows my site to a crawl. What am I doing wrong here?

```
wp_enqueue_script('dropzone','wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/js/dropzone.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('my-script','wp-content/themes/storefront/footer.php', array('jquery','dropzone'));
 $drop_param = array(
  'upload'=>admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=handle_dropped_media' ),
  'delete'=>admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=handle_delete_media' ),
);
wp_localize_script('my-script','dropParam', $drop_param);



add_action( 'wp_ajax_handle_dropped_media', 'BMP_handle_dropped_media' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_dropped_media', 'BMP_handle_dropped_media' );

function BMP_handle_dropped_media() {
   // status_header(200);
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = $upload_dir['path'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    $newupload = 0;

    if ( !empty($_FILES) ) {
        $files = $_FILES;
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $newfile = array (
                    'name' => $file['name'],
                    'type' => $file['type'],
                    'tmp_name' => $file['tmp_name'],
                    'error' => $file['error'],
                    'size' => $file['size']
            );

            $_FILES = array('upload'=>$newfile);
            foreach($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                $newupload = my_handle_attachment( $file, $post_id );
            }
        }
    }

    echo $newupload;    
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_handle_delete_media', 'BMP_handle_delete_media' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_delete_media', 'BMP_handle_delete_media' );
function BMP_handle_delete_media(){

    if( isset($_REQUEST['media_id']) ){

        $post_id = absint( $_REQUEST['media_id'] );

        $status = wp_delete_attachment($post_id, true);

        if( $status )
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK'));
        else
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'FAILED'));
    }

    die();
}
```

Thanks for any help.
Heres where I pulled the code from originally.
[How to integrate Dropzonejs with wordpress media handler in frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411257/how-to-integrate-dropzonejs-with-wordpress-media-handler-in-frontend/41295520)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your wp_enqueue_script() calls in a function:

```
function your_styles_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script('dropzone','wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/js/dropzone.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script','wp-content/themes/storefront/footer.php', array('jquery','dropzone'));
    $drop_param = array(
        'upload'=>admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=handle_dropped_media' ),
        'delete'=>admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=handle_delete_media' ),
);
    wp_localize_script('my-script','dropParam', $drop_param);
}
```

And the relevant action hook, as needed for your use case:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'your_styles_scripts' );
```

or

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_styles_scripts' );
```

Comment: The functionality works but its still slowing down the site.

Comment: @tsea That would be a completely separate question that has a thousand different factors that could be playing into it based on your hosting set up, etc. I.e. If you're on slow shared hosting, things are going to be slow.

Comment: I dont think so my page speeds on pingdom are great i have dedicated server and without using wp_enqueue_script() my site is very fast but as soon as i use it the site slows down alot.

Comment: Are you using the Storefront theme currently? Also, does the setup actually work currently?