# Submit data with button Dropzone.js

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

This is first time using dropzone and im trying to upload data with it but i get:

```
app.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Dropzone.processQueue is not a function // Using jquery
```

This my template layout:

```
<form id="form1"enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
  {{render_field(form.quantity_user)}}

  <label>Upload Songs</label>
  <label class="button small-12 hollow" id="songs">Upload File
    <!--{{form.song (class="show-for-sr songs")}}-->
  </label>

  <p class="help-text">Upload up to 700MB in music and up to 2 images.</p>
  <button id="next" class="button small-12">Next <i class="fi-arrow-right"></i></button>
</form>
```

I'm not attaching Dropzone to the form because it isn't necessary(as far as i know).

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  $('#songs').dropzone({

    url: '/upload/',
    previewTemplate: $('#list-container').html(),
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    autoQueue: false,
    previewsContainer: '#list-container',
    paramName: 'song',
    params: {
      quantity_user: $('#quantity_user').val(),
      csrf_token: $('#csrf_token').val()
    },
    init: function(){
      $('#next').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        Dropzone.processQueue();
      })


    }

  })
```

Comment: This can be deleted solved the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload and delete files from dropzone.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375389/how-to-upload-and-delete-files-from-dropzone-js)